# time counter python GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, time

I am trying to get the number of seconds betwen when a query has been launched, and when I refresh a page.
I'm using the following code:

```
Import time

last_queried = 0

def top_blogs(update = False):
    blogs = memcache.get(key)
    global last_queried
    if update:
        blogs = GqlQuery("Select * from Blog Order by created Desc limit 10")
        last_queried = time.time()
        memcache.set(key, blogs)
    return blogs
```

When I display the page:

```
class FrontpageHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        global last_queried
        blogs = top_blogs()
        render_time=time.time()
        time_lapse = render_time - last_queried
        self.render("front.html", blogs = blogs, time=time_lapse)
```

It seems that i'm getting in time_lapse, not the difference in seconds but the time since Epoch, what am I doing wrong?

Regards

Edit: for clarification purposes, here is when I call the top_blogs function, which should update my query and the variable last_queried in theory:

```
class NewPostHandler(Handler):
    def post(self):
        subject = self.request.get("subject")
        content = self.request.get("content")
        if subject and content:
            a = Blog(parent = blog_key(), subject=subject, content=content)
            a.put()
            top_blogs(True)
            self.redirect("/blog/%s" %str(a.key().id()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that when importing something in python don't use capital letters.

You can try the following example and see where you get:

```
from datetime import datetime  

last_queried = datetime.now()
render_time = datetime.now()

time_lapse = last_queried - render_time
time_lapse.seconds() # -> number
time_lapse.microseconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you initialize the last_queried with 0 and when you call top_blogs you do not specify the update (which default to False), hence it never goes to the if block which change the last_queried.

Comment: I thought I specified the update when writing 'if update:', doesn't it imply that we update when update == True? and in that case last_queried is being updated with time.time() ? Thx

Comment: That is true, but your 'update' variable is False in this case (default to False since you're not passing in the value).

Comment: I have another piece of code, which updates with update = True. 'class NewPostHandler(Handler): def post(self): subject = self.request.get('subject') content = self.request.get('content') if subject and content: a = Blog(parent = blog_key(), subject=subject, content=content) a.put() top_blogs(True)   self.redirect("/blog/%s" %str(a.key().id()))' This one triggers top_blogs with update=True and should update last_queried, but it doesn't???

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but you print the time_laps in FrontpageHandler where update=False. The NewPostHandler is indeed update the last_queried, but I'm not sure when that endpoint is triggered. Why don't you just print the value of last_queried after you assign it, just to make sure that code path is triggered